# How can I share a $scope function among a number of different controllers?

Tags: angularjs

I have a number of different controllers. Each of these controllers makes use of 
some functions like this:

```
    $scope.isNotString = function (str) {
        return (typeof str !== "string");
    }
```

I don't want to keep adding this function to each controller. Is there a way I 
can put the functions in a file and then just reference that file from each
controller?

Comment: put it in some "parent" controller , so it will be inherited in all descendants controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options:

**Define the function on the root scope (or a parent scope)**

It will also appear on child scopes (thanks to [prototypal inheritance](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)) except in isolate scopes.

**Declare a service**

This is a good solution if you need to share something with isolate scopes. If your app is called `myApp`:

```
myApp.service('stringUtil', function () {
  this.isNotString = function (str) {
    return (typeof str !== "string");
  };
});

myApp.directive('something', function (stringUtil) {
  return {
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
      scope.isNotString = stringUtil.isNotString;
    }
  };
});
```

**Use a directive controller**

Directives attached to the same tag can share their controllers. This doesn't seem useful in your case, but helps if you need a shared state on the tag. For example, I have a directive `modal` that shares functions to open a modal.

```
myApp.directive('modal', function () {
  return {
    controller: function () {
      this.openModal = function() {…};

      this.close = function() {…};
    }
  };
});

myApp.directive('userSettings', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',

    require: 'modal',

    link: function (scope, element, attr, modalController) {
      scope.close = modalController.close;
    }
  };
}};
```

The markup would be:

```
<user-settings modal>
  <a ng-click="close()">Close</a>

  <h1>User Settings</h1>
</user-settings>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a parent controller for all controllers then its better to add there or you can create a utilityService and inject it to each of controllers where its necessary.

If you add it in a parent controller then automatically all the child controllers inherit the parent controller's scope.

Answer (score 1):

In order for two controller to share data or methods you create a service that you inject into whatever controllers you want, thus each controller has access to that services methods.  I've provided you with a working example showing two controllers with a shared services injected into both of them and each controller is calling the same method from the shared service.

```
app.service('myService',function(){
   this.sharedFunction = function() {
      //do some stuff
   };
});

myCntrl1($scope,myService) {
   $scope.doSomething = function() {
      myService.sharedFunction();
   }
}

myCntrl2($scope,myService) {
   $scope.doSomething = function() {
      myService.sharedFunction();
   }
}
```